# send sms to a number using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, phonegap

I have used this code to send sms in my mobile app using angularjs.    `<a ng-href={{'sms:'+data.mobile1}}><i class="material-icons">message</i></a>` But its not working. Can someone help me?

Comment: Try putting "" for ng-href and if it didn't work, maybe try ng-href=" ' sms:' + {{data.mobile1}} "

Comment: sorry do you have a service trought send sms?

Comment: No..I just want to open default sms app of device. and I tried  ng-href=" ' sms:' + {{data.mobile1}} "  .Its not working.

Comment: @Vivz Its not working.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Vivz No.But its not working in mobile. If i run it in chrome i am getting Cannot GET /'%20sms:'%20+%208970538990 this error

Comment: Maybe try ng-href="sms:{{data.mobile1}}" . I think some space is being read in the url

Comment: @Vivz  still its nor working.IS there any other way to do this?

Comment: Create ng-click to call a function where you create the url u want and change the location with that

Comment: @Vivz how to do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150164/discussion-between-vivz-and-amshu).

Comment: @Vivz Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind to `ng-href` the following way

```
ng-href="sms:{{data.mobile1}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"sms:{{data.mobile1}}"
```

Should be within quotes.

For more : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref